# Select with limit for the same id

Tags: sql, mariadb, greatest-n-per-group

i have 3 tables

Posts_comments

```
comment_id, comment_post_id, comment_value, comment_time comment_user_id
1           1                test           DATETIME     1
2           1                test2          DATETIME     2
3           2                test3          DATETIME     2
4           1                test4          DATETIME     2
5           1                test5          DATETIME     1
6           1                test6          DATETIME     2
```

Members

```
member_id member_fistname member_lastname member_slug
1         John            Doe             john-doe
2         Test            User            test-user
```

Members_photos

```
member_user_id member_photo_type member_photo_name
1              2                 test.jpg
2              2                 test2.jpg
```

And i have sql

```
SELECT 
      posts_comments.comment_id, 
      posts_comments.comment_post_id, 
      posts_comments.comment_value, 
      posts_comments.comment_time, 
      members.member_id, 
      members.member_lastname, 
      members.member_fistname, 
      members_photos.member_photo_name 
FROM 
    posts_comments 
LEFT JOIN 
         members ON posts_comments.comment_user_id = members.member_id 
LEFT JOIN 
         members_photos ON members.member_id = members_photos.member_user_id 
AND 
   members_photos.member_photo_type = 2 
ORDER BY 
        posts_comments.comment_time DESC 
LIMIT 4
```

But this query show only last 4 comments independently from the comment_post_id. 
In this case i want to show last 4 comments for every comment_post_id (in this example: 4 comments where comment_post_id = 1 and 1 comment where comment_post_id = 2). 
I hope I wrote it clearly enough. 
Thx 4 help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `row_number()` window function if it mariadb version `MariaDB 10.2.0` or greatere

```
select a.* from (    SELECT 
              posts_comments.comment_id, 
              posts_comments.comment_post_id, 
              posts_comments.comment_value, 
              posts_comments.comment_time, 
              members.member_id, 
              members.member_lastname, 
              members.member_fistname, 
              members_photos.member_photo_name,
             row_number()over(partition by  posts_comments.comment_post_id order by posts_comments.comment_time desc) rn
        FROM 
            posts_comments 
        LEFT JOIN 
                 members ON posts_comments.comment_user_id = members.member_id 
        LEFT JOIN 
                 members_photos ON members.member_id = members_photos.member_user_id 
        AND 
           members_photos.member_photo_type = 2
    ) a where a.rn<=4
```

Comment: Ok i tested this query dont work on 10.1.37-MariaDB :/ "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(partition by posts_comments.comment_post_id order by posts_comments.comment_time'"

Comment: This sql return only 2 comments not max 4 where comment_post_id is the same

Comment: @Polo195pl https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3 can you plz create your table with data in fiddle link

Comment: @Polo195pl in where a.rn<=4 is needed i was mistakenly put it =4

Comment: lol after change from = to <= works perfect :) Thx mate :) I must read about how this query work ;)